# Not able to play a video in ios6

Tags: iphone

I'm not able to play the video using MPMoviePlayerController, this is my code

```
NSString *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MLL_Video"ofType:@"mp4"];
MPMoviePlayerController *theMoviPlayer;
theMoviPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
theMoviPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
theMoviPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 60, 320, 350);

self.myPlayer=theMoviPlayer;
[self.view addSubview:self.myPlayer.view];
[self.myPlayer prepareToPlay];
[self.myPlayer play];
```

But it does not work even used the following code also:

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
moviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.frame;
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
moviePlayer.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
[moviePlayer.moviePlayer play];
```

But it also does not work, seems to be some bug in latest xcode(4.4), Please share if any body has a solution on this.

Comment: what is displayed on the screen ? a black screen or something else ? also check with **.m4v** files

Comment: a black screen and nothing happens, even tried all the possible ways but dont know why its not working